# Explicit mention intended semicolon

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, warnings

### Problem

I used an empty statement and am aware of that. So how can I disable the compiler warning?

> warning C4390: ';' : empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?

There might be a way of explicitly say that I want an empty statement.

### Background

In a development environment the debug function should display the error message and exit the application. In a productive release it should do nothing. So I wrote a macro for that.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#define Debug(text) { cout << "Error: " << text; cin.get(); exit(1); }
#else
#define Debug(text) ;
#endif
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to avoid a macro? Use an inline function and implement it conditionally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The common idiom for an empty statement macro is this:

```
#define Debug(text) do {} while (0)
```

As Ben points out in a comment, it is prudent to use this technique in both versions of the macro.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#define Debug(text) do { cout << "Error: " << text; cin.get(); exit(1); } while (0)
#else
#define Debug(text) do {} while (0)
#endif
```

This idiom is discussed in many places. For example:

- http://bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/DoWhile.html
- http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/empty_statement_macro.html

Comment: @BenVoigt - I'm somewhat clueless most of the time, and I'm trying to interpret the intent of your comment.  Was it tongue-in-cheek because `do{}while(0)` isn't actually empty, or was it that both versions of the macro should be encapsulated in such a construct?  And if the latter, why?

Comment: @phonetagger: That both versions benefit.  David interpreted it correctly.

Comment: -1 There is no point in using the `do {} while (0)`. the construct is used to be able to have multiple statements in a macro and support use e.g. between `if` and `else`. it serves no purpose here.

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly tell the compiler you're not doing anything

```
(void)0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another explicit expression for doing nothing:

```
void();
```

This syntax uses a C++ default constructor for `void` type, so it won't work in C.

It's the shortest valid code which contains the word `void`, so may be marginally better than `(void)0`.

Answer (score 0):

`Debug` is used as a function-like macro but does not act like one:

```
if( some_condition ) Debug(); else { blah }    // Ooops
```

Also, it messes with the standard output stream, includes different headers for debug versus release build, uses a reserved symbol (starts with underscore followed by uppercase) `_DEBUG` (did you mean to use standard `NDEBUG`?) and needlessly uses a non-standard exit value.

So instead of the current

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#define Debug(text) { cout << "Error: " << text; cin.get(); exit(1); }
#else
#define Debug(text) ;
#endif
```

do

```
#ifndef DEBUGGING_H
#define DEBUGGING_H

#include <iostream>      // std::cerr, std::endl
#include <stdlib.h>      // exit, EXIT_FAILURE

#ifdef MYDEBUG
#   define Debug(text) ::debugging::sayByeAndTerminate( text )
#else
#   define Debug(text)
#endif

namespace debugging {
    inline void sayByeAndTerminate( char const* const text )
    {
        using namespace std;
        cerr << "Error: " << text; cin.get(); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}  // namespace debugging
```

Note that the code above does *not* use a silly

```
do {} while( false )
```

nor the double-silly

```
(void)0
```

because there is no need to write something just to get nothing.

Nothing is a perfectly good nothing.

For the warning: I'm unable to reproduce it with Visual C++ 11 (please provide a *complete* example that exhibits the behavior) but just **turn it off**. Don't adjust the code to accomodate the compiler in this. Just turn off the warning.

Disclaimer: off-the-cuff code, untouched by compilers' hands.

Comment: `_DEBUG` is Microsofts debug flag. There is no need for a namespace or an own debug flag for me. But thank's for `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

Comment: @sharethis: I know that Visual C++ uses that flag. Using it yourself makes the code needlessly non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to disable the compilation warning is to put at start of the code the following:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4390 )
```